# Get the previous day Date without changing the date format PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a variable `$date` I want to get the previous day date in the same format as the `$date`in,

For example, if the date is in `"Y-m-d"` format I need a function one_day_back

```
 function one_day_back($date){

   return date("same format as $date has, in this case "Y-m-d", strtotime($date,"-1 day"));
 }
```

But the problem is I don't always know the format of the `$date` so I can't specify a particular format in date (like "Y-m-d")

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know the format of your input date you're pretty much SOL anyway. Is the correct result for `10-10-10`: `9-10-10`, `10-9-10`, or `10-10-9`…?

Comment: This would only be achievable if you passed the date format with the $date into this function _or_ passed some \DateTime object.

Comment: As deceze said, you're out of luck unless you're prepared to write a TON of IF statements attempting to validate all the possible date variations ;)

Comment: If you don’t _know_ the format, then you will have to _guess_ it, by comparing it to a given list of possible formats. That that might not allow for a 1:1 correlation in every single case, should be clear.

Comment: To follow on @deceze's point, you might be table to determine some date formats, but even that wouldn't be conclusive given the date 1/2/2017. Is that January 2nd or February 1st? If you knew the list of date formats that were possible, then maybe use a switch or chain of if statements.

Comment: 02-01-2017, 01-02-2017 can you decide is it d-m-y or m-d-y ?

Comment: You can try using Carbon nesbot. It is a PHP datetime library that is easy to implement and to use. I've use it before on my thesis project using Laravel since it was a integrated library on Laravel, I used it and I love it to use every time I want to manipulate date and time.

Comment: ok Thanks, There are various date format in the script, So i think i need to specify the date format in the function, I thought it might be possible some other way, Anyway thanks to all :)

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting the question. It's a fair question, I think the answers in the comments are a fair explanation as to _why_ this can't be done..

Comment: Oh come on, it's not that hard. You make a list of possible formats. You detect the format with preg_match, create the date, and see if the date created is the same as the date being passed in.

Comment: You should standardise on *one* internal date format to be used, preferably even use `DateTime` objects everywhere. Don't maintain a mishmash of different date formats inside your own code.

Comment: @aynber - OK, determine what date I mean by "02-01-2018" without knowing the format I'm using please.

Comment: `strtotime` can convert some known date format to unix timestamp. Sadly, it doesn't return which format it guess. ^^

Comment: @invisal Even the almighty `strtotime` (`</sarcasm>`) won't magically guess what exactly you *mean* by `10-10-10`…

Comment: @deceze, that's why I use the word "guess". Because not all guess are right ^^

Comment: @deceze, technically it will magically guess what exactly is meant by 10-10-10, though it's likely that guess would be wrong.

Comment: @invisal Which is why *guessing* is an invalid strategy in programming except in very specific circumstances involving fuzzy user input…

Comment: @Jack Well, it's a 1 in 3 chance really… :D

Comment: @Jackhardcastle Okay, those are tricky. Now you've got me staring at the functions I made to see if it's okay.

Comment: Chances are you'll only be using a single locale @aynber so they'll be fine for _your_ application, however in this case OP made a point of expecting different formats, where this strategy won't work.